# Multi level directory structure for libraries in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

> **EDIT:** So it was all about capitalization of the library name. Once I changed $this->**P**rofessional->initialize ( 1 ); to
> $this->**p**rofessional->initialize ( 1 ); it worked.

**How to access library stored in multi level directory structure ?**

Here is my library directory structure

```
application
-libraries
--User
---User.php (Parent class)
---Admin
----Admin.php (Child class of User.php)
---Professional
----Professional.php (Child class of User.php)
```

**In the controller**

```
class Test extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct (  ) { parent::__construct (  ); }

public function user ()
{
    
        $this->load->library ( 'User/Professional/Professional' );
        
        $this->Professional->initialize ( 1 );
    
}

}
```

The class/library gets loaded but I can not access it like this `$this->Public`

> **Error Message**: Undefined property: Test::$Professional
>
> **Error Message**: Call to a member function initialize() on a non-object

Answer (score 1):

I attempted to replicate using Codeigniter 3 and found that you can do it using your structure. The only error I was able to reproduce was naming a class **public**, since public is a keyword in PHP, you may be running into issues using that name.

## File Structure

```
/libraries
../User
../User/User.php
../User/Public
../User/Public/Pub.php
```

## User.php - Parent

```
class User
{
    function __construct()
    {
        echo "1";
    }
}
```

## Pub.php - Child

```
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../User.php');

class Pub extends User
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        echo "2";
    }

    function init()
    {
        echo "True";
    }
}
```

## Implementation

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('User/Public/Pub');
        $this->pub->init();
    }
```

## Output

```
12True
```

Comment: That's strange. I am still getting the error. The names in my original post are only placeholders actual names are different.

Comment: Whoa..... You know what, when I changed `$this->Professional->initialize` to `$this->professional->initialize` it worked. Thanks for your efforts :) it helped.

Comment: @StudentX happy to help